# Custom QGraphicsItem mousePressEvent for single click works only when double click

Tags: qt, mouseevent, qgraphicsitem

I have the following mousePressEvent, it's works fine but only when double clicking the mouse, I want it to work only when single click on the mouse button.

```
void MapNode::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    isClicked *= -1;
    QGraphicsItem::mousePressEvent(event);
    update();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: So you have put in debug output or breakpoints in the method, and confirmed that it is only called when double clicking?

Comment: Yes indeed I have put breakpoints in the method, and it is only called when double clicking :S
But I did notice something, I have a custom QGraphicsView (which holds the scene that contains all the custom QGraphicsItem's) which also call mousePressEvent, and the custom QGraphicsView mousePressEvent works with single click.

Answer (score 3):

I have a mousePressEvent in the parent of my custom QGraphicsItem, which is a custom QGraphicsView, only needed to add inside the custom QGraphicsView mousePressEvent the following line of code in the beginning of the method: `QGraphicsView::mousePressEvent(event);`, so now single click works fine, probably the event on the parent blocked the event on the child.